# How to retrieve a list of rows for a given username and userID from Rooms database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I have a Rooms database which stores flight information, and I want to retrieve a list of flights which are associated with a given username and userID. I am attaching herewith the code for my activity

**Activity code**

```
 userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(ReportListingActivity.this, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
                user_details = getUsers();
                user_name = user_details[0];
                user_id = user_details[1];
   

            }
        });

        flightViewModel.getAllFlights().observe(this, new Observer<List<Flight>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Flight> flight_list) {

                if (flight_list.size() == 0) return;

                for(int i = 0; i <flight_list.size();i++){
                    String flightnumber = flight_list.get(i).getFlightNumber();
                    String departuredate = flight_list.get(i).getDate();
                    String status = flight_list.get(i).getFlight_closure_status();
                    String user_name = flight_list.get(i).getName();
                    String user_id = flight_list.get(i).getStaffID();

                    reportitems.add(new ReportItem(flightnumber,departuredate,status, user_name, user_id));


                }
                mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                flightViewModel.getAllFlights().removeObservers(ReportListingActivity.this);
            }
        });
```

From UserViewModel I get the userID, and from FlightViewModel I want to get the flights which are associated with that username and userID. I already have a username and userID attribute in the Flight_Table.

Below is the query I have written in FlightDao to get a flight given username and userID

**FlightDao**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM flight_table WHERE (name = :name and staffID = :id)")
public Flight getFlightReports(String name, String id);
```

I want to display all the flights that are associated with the given name and id. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is? You already get the flights with the given name and ID from your database. I don't exactly how it is done in Java, but I guess you should return a list of Flights from your database instead of a single object

Comment: okay, returning a list of Flights works, thanks!